# Writetable including cell vectors without auto-delimiting the values and adding fields

Tags: matlab

If you have a table with e.g.

```
T = 
  Cell_Vec      Scalar  
____________    _____
[1x3 double]    22497
```

and use `writetable(T,'filename.txt','Delimiter','tab')` the table gets corrupt since it will not look the same when reading it again (fields are added). Matlab suggest to save it as a `.mat` but this is not a good solution in my case since the file format must be more stable and work in other programs (such as excel/calc).

From Matlab:

[Matlab help page](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html)

T =

```
            Age    Height    Weight    BloodPressure
            ___    ______    ______    _____________

Smith       38     71        176       124     93   
Johnson     43     69        163       109     77   
Williams    38     64        131       125     83   
Jones       40     67        133       117     75   
Brown       49     64        119       122     80
```

Write the table, T, to a comma delimited text file, called myPatientData.dat, and display the file contents.

```
writetable(T,'myPatientData.dat','WriteRowNames',true)
type 'myPatientData.dat'

Row,Age,Height,Weight,BloodPressure_1,BloodPressure_2  
Smith,38,71,176,124,93  
Johnson,43,69,163,109,77  
Williams,38,64,131,125,83  
Jones,40,67,133,117,75  
Brown,49,64,119,122,80
```

But I would like the variable name "BloodPressure" to be intact, so that:

```
Row,Age,Height,Weight,BloodPressure  
Smith,38,71,176,124 93  
Johnson,43,69,163,109 77  
Williams,38,64,131,125 83  
Jones,40,67,133,117 75  
Brown,49,64,119,122 80
```

Any suggestions? Frustrating since the `writetable` function seems most convenient, is a simple rewrite possible?

If I make a `.txt` file and manually add space between `Cell_Vec` values and tab between variables `readtable` will at least work fine...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the two values like that, the easiest thing to do would be to convert them to a formatted string which your other programs can then parse.

```
T = table([1;2;3], [124, 90; 130 40; 150 10], 'VariableNames', {'Age', 'BP'});

%// Convert blood pressure to "Systolic/Diastolic"
T.BP = cellfun(@(x)sprintf('%d/%d',x(1),x(2)), num2cell(T.BP, 2), 'uni', 0);

writetable(T,'myPatientData.dat','WriteRowNames',true)

type('myPatientData.dat')

%// Age,BP
%// 1,124/90
%// 2,130/40
%// 3,150/10
```